# Numpy Add All Combinations of Vectors

Tags: python, numpy, combinations

What is the most numerically efficient way to add all the combinations of two arrays of vectors? For example what I want is the following:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
b = np.array([[7,8,9], [10,11,12]])
[ai + bj for ai in a for bj in b]
```

Gives

```
[array([ 8, 10, 12]),
 array([11, 13, 15]),
 array([11, 13, 15]),
 array([14, 16, 18])]
```

It's a meshgrid with vectors instead of primary data types.

I've tried somewhat explicitly constructing the meshgrid results, which is faster than the list comprehension:

```
a_tile = np.tile(a, (2, 1))
```

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

```
b_repeat = np.repeat(b, 2, axis=0)
```

```
array([[ 7,  8,  9],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

```
a_tile + b_repeat
```

```
array([[ 8, 10, 12],
       [11, 13, 15],
       [11, 13, 15],
       [14, 16, 18]])
```

Is this as efficient as it gets? I was looking for a way to broadcast the arrays so that the grid isn't explicitly constructed.

Comment: Since you're using two different repeat methods (tile + repeat), I don't think there's any broadcasting method available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
b = np.array([[7,8,9], [10,11,12]])

(a[..., None] + b.T).transpose(0, 2, 1).reshape(-1, 3)
```

It gives:

```
array([[ 8, 10, 12],
       [11, 13, 15],
       [11, 13, 15],
       [14, 16, 18]])
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! In my crude timing tests this solution seems to be only slightly faster than my above tile-repeat implementation while about twice as fast as the list comprehension. 
I didn't test how it scales with array size, maybe the tile-repeat method will slow down when creating much larger arrays.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [numpy.broadcast_to](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) to broadcast an array

```
N = 2 #number of repeats
your_req_array = np.broadcast_to(b.T, (N,b.shape[1], b.shape[0])).transpose(2,0,1).reshape(-1,b.shape[1]) + np.broadcast_to(a, (N,a.shape[0], a.shape[1])).reshape(-1,b.shape[1])
```

Comment: This method works as well and produces timing similar to bb1's answer. However bb1's implicit broadcasting is more readable.